# Is there any way to import fields for a new form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have an existing form in another system.

Is there any way to import fields for a new form, or do I have to create it all over again?

Second, can I import my existing entries then have the new form for new entries.  I'd like to keep all data together.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Cognito Forms support.  Cognito Forms provides import [for Wufoo Forms and entries](https://www.cognitoforms.com/l/wufoo-alternative).  If your form is with another solution, then you will need to rebuild the form and entries cannot be imported.

Comment: Nick, I have an idea. Cognito supports pre-filling a single form row using JSON. A javascript page could be setup to walk through the rows of a Google Sheet, submitting each automatically to Cognito.  In turn, Cognito could sync changes made in Cognito back to the same Google Sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Loren, Nick, can you provide a guide or more information for achieving that process? (submitting values to an existing entry via JavaScript)